# React Native: is it possible to "snap" a FlatList scroll items

Tags: javascript, reactjs, native

I want to use a FlatList component as a Picker, in order to give it that feel I want the vertical items to "snap" each one, this is not like yur typical scrolling behaviour, I don't know how to explain better and I'm not sure this is possible at all but I'd like to hear from other seasoned developers.

```
<FlatList
  decelerationRate={"fast"} 
  data={modalPickerStore.pickerData} 
  keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.title+index.toString()}
  renderItem={({ item }) => 
    <TouchableHighlight
      onPress={()=>{ 
        modalPickerStore.setSelectedPickerData(item.value) 
      }} 
      style={{ 
        width:'100%',
        height:50,
        flexDirection:'column',
        alignItems:'center',
        justifyContent:'space-between'
      }}>
        <Icon name={item.icon} size={30} color="black"/>
        <Text style={{ 
          color: 'rgb(255,52,89)',
          textAlign: 'center',
          fontSize: 16, 
          fontWeight: 'bold' 
        }}>{ item.title }</Text>
        <Text style={{ 
          color:'rgb(255,52,89)', 
          textAlign:'center', 
          fontSize:16, 
          fontWeight:'bold' 
        }}>Hecho</Text>
      </TouchableHighlight>}
    />
```

Comment: Have you figured out how to do it?